# How to automatically delete a record according to end date in django

Tags: python, django, date, model

I have a django app with the model below

```
Class Promotion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

So during the creation of the promotion record, we will set a `start date` and `end date` to it, so what all the functionality is when the `current date` is greater than the `end date`, the record should be automatically deleted from the database, or else an email will be sent.... so some kind of these situations.

So can any one please let me know, how to handle these situations, i mean when the current date is greater than the promotion date do something.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that deletes any of the `Promotion` records that are "expired", i.e. their `end_date` has passed. Then a scheduled task, a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in Ubuntu (and Unix-flavoured systems), will call the management command at the schedule you specify via `crontab`, in this case least once daily.

Edit: Alternatively you could use `celery` "Period Tasks" to run scheduled tasks, docs [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a pre_save signal check to check dates before entering a new record.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: whether signals would slow the process anywhere ?, can u show me an example on how to do it with signals efficiently ?

Comment: I can't write the code for you. Adding a signal will not add any noticeable time.

Comment: If you at least TRY to write the code and can't figure out an error, THAT we can help with! So try it, break it apart, and try it again. If you're still stuck.. Post it!