# Django: automatically delete records

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-commands

I am trying to delete records in real time or automatically similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715528/how-to-automatically-delete-a-record-according-to-end-date-in-django)

As i have understand (I am a newbie) you need write a management command but I am having a hard time grasping the concept and how can it be in real time? Can someone point me in the right direction? I am very confused. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? You don't need a management command to delete records

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you want to know about custom Django commands can be found in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/

Basically, you need to create a `management/commands` directory, so your folder structure looks like this:

```
app/
    ... (some stuff you're having in your app directory)
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            delete_all.py
```

Now in `delete_all.py` you want to declare a new command class extending `BaseCommand` and responsible for all your logic. The easiest implementation of such will look like this:

```
# delete_all.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from app.models import MyModel


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('Deleting all MyModel records!')
        MyModel.objects.all().delete()
        print('Successfully deleted all MyModel records!')
```

Now you can access your command with `manage.py`:

```
python manage.py delete_all
```

Comment: I see so if i need to delete some expired records i would need run manage.py? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: that directory should be `app/management/commands` with an `__init__.py` in the management and commands directories

Comment: @Chris Montanaro Thanks, you're right! I edited my answer according to your suggestion

Comment: @Juan Carlos Asuncion yes, and if you need your command to run every fixed time interval, you need to set up a cron job which will execute the command for you

Comment: Thanks, will try for a bit

Comment: Thanks! Really helped