# Django - before model create

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
book(book_id, release_year, book_number_by_release_year)
```

Field `book_number_by_release_year` must be automatically generated and incremented by 1 within the `release_year` field for new model instances.

What is the best way to do this in Django? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

from django docs you can [create custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) and if your operating system is unix based this command will automatically called when it's date is what you have set, looking form example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) above

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from polls.models import Question as Poll

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('poll_ids', nargs='+', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for poll_id in options['poll_ids']:
            try:
                poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
            except Poll.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError('Poll "%s" does not exist' % poll_id)
            # you can type your logic here 
            poll.opened = False
            poll.save()

            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Successfully closed poll "%s"' % poll_id))
```

this will automatically close the polls that is created by user
for your case

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
        .
        .

            # you can type your logic here 
            if (datetime.date.today() - self.release_year) == 0:
            self.book_number_by_release_year +=1
            self.save()
```

consider adding your attempts and models.py for more detailed answer and for good question
check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19715570/13961837) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pre_save` signal, or override the `save` method. I prefer the former as we're not changing methods defined by `django`. Here is a rough implementation on using `pre_save` signal:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.IntegerField()
    release_year = models.IntegerField()
    book_number_by_release_year = models.IntegerField()


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Book)
def populate_book_number_by_release_year(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # fetch the last book_id given
    args = Book.objects.filter(release_year=instance.release_year)
    max_value = args.aggregate(Max('book_number_by_release_year'))
    
    if max_value == None:
        instance.book_number_by_release_year=0
    else:
        instance.book_number_by_release_year=max_value['book_number_by_release_year']
```

PS: Do note that there's a race condition possibility, like any other `autoincrement` function.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `AutoField` for the above use case.
Instead of relying on a `pre_save` signal, we can make our changes at model definition like so:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.IntegerField()
    release_year = models.IntegerField()
    book_number_by_release_year = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)
```

Link to the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#autofield

Comment: Thank you. But, how can i generate separate autonumbering for every year in field release_year?